# Concatenate string in the template

Tags: django-filter, chicagoboss

I have to prepare a url on the fly in the template by passing some variables to it.

```
{% with init_sync_url='/baseurl/formid/'|add:form_id|add:'/context/' %}
     =={{init_sync_url}}===
       {% myother_tag goto_url=init_sync_url  %}
{% endwith %}
```

This code works pretty fine. Which also shows me the output on the template:

```
==/baseurl/formid/abcd123/context/===
```

Which is OK. But after that when I add the a context variable `cntxt`
containing a string like - `'01-01-1030'`

```
{% with init_sync_url='/baseurl/formid/'|add:form_id|add:'/context/'|add:cntxt %}
       {% myother_tag goto_url=init_sync_url  %}
{% endwith %}
```

OR

```
 {% with init_sync_url='/baseurl/formid/'|add:form_id|add:'/context/' %}
           {% myother_tag goto_url=init_sync_url|add:cntxt  %}
 {% endwith %}
```

This throws an error!!! Don't know, why?
I expect the output if I log the line in the template inside `with` tag
`=={{init_sync_url}}===`:

```
==/baseurl/formid/abcd123/context/01-01-1030===
```

- Is the hyphen("-") causing something?

(Detailed error in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/takp9bSa))

**NOTE** - Just In case if any django developer knows the answer to my question. There is not much difference in the `filters` of `django` & `Chicagoboss`.